Issue with move folder API in Microsoft Graph when Email ID contains "/"
When attempting to move a folder using the following endpoint:
Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{EmailId}/move
I'm encountering an error when the EmailId parameter contains a "/" symbol. Despite trying to encode the Email ID, the API continues to return an error.
It's important to note that the API works as expected when the Email ID does not contain a "/" symbol.
I have already attempted to encode the Email ID using URL encoding, but the issue persists. Additionally, escaping the "/" character did not resolve the problem.
The API should be able to move the folder regardless of whether the Email ID contains a "/" symbol.
Following is the error
{"error":{"code":"RequestBroker--ParseUri","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'vUqoAAAIBDAAAANbsh1sqmahFnro5xH'."}}`

Following is the code (it is working fine if emailId didn't has "/"

`using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    string encodedEmailId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(emailId);

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{encodedEmailId}/move");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    request.Content = new StringContent($"{{\"DestinationId\": \"{folderId}\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    string errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}


I’d raise it with Microsoft directly.

You can try an alternative way https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages('{encodedEmailId}')/move, but from my test, in case of / in message id, it throws bad request. Definitely it's server side issue.

Where are getting the Id's from ? The Graph /rest Id's should be base64URL meaning that any / would get substituted for _ (there are a number of other rules as well https://base64.guru/standards/base64url) . If you sourcing the Id's from EWS or exov3 cmdlets then you'll need to do some conversion first.

@GlenScales what you mean?

Where are you getting the "Email ID" from ? Rest/GraphId are Base64 URL safe meaning they won't contain a "/" character. If you have obtained the ID from another API eg EWS these Id's aren't base64 safe so may contain "/" because that is a valid character in base64encoding.  You can also use imutableId's so convert whatever Id you have to a immutable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

@GlenScales I am getting "Email ID" from Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId using this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

So it depends on the client but from the error you getting I'm pretty sure you getting the ewsId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api you need to covert that to rest using the Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId method.

@GlenScales Thanks alot, it is working fine, can you write a answer so that I can mark it solved?

@GlenScales can you check my comment in your answer section ?

@GlenScales can you connect with me on LinkedIn? :-) I sent you a request from Obaid Ahmed.

If you are using the EWSId from an Outlook Addin you must first convert that to a RESTId (which is base64URL safe) using the Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId method see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api for more detail.

just one last thing I am stuck with. I use the token from EWSId, and it will expire after some time. I am unable to create a refresh token. Can you guide me? I want to create the refresh token on the server side, not the client side. This means I will take the token from the client side (EWSId) the first time, then I will continue using it on the server side.

Its by design as being able to use a token that way would be a bad thing from a security point of view. For an Add-in the security context needs to come from the client and needs to be driven/renewed that way. If you want to have a refresh token and server driven process then you need to go outside of SSO and authenticate the user again in your process. Still not a good design for server side apps the client credentials flow is best.

can you connect with me on LinkedIn? :-) I sent you a request from Obaid Ahmed.
